# defStyleRes has no effect in custom View (RelativeLayout)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

The following constructor call attempts to style my custom `RelativeLayout2` using the `defStyleRes` parameter but it has no effect. I ported this sample project to AndroidStudio and it worked ok.

```
public RelativeLayout2(Context context, IAttributeSet attributeSet) 
    : base(context, attributeSet, 0, Resource.Style.RelativeLayout2)
{
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

  <style name="RelativeLayout2">
    <item name="android:layout_width">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">300dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#114499</item>
    <item name="android:padding">50dp</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**activity_main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InflationWithStyle.RelativeLayout2 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="needs some style."/>

</InflationWithStyle.RelativeLayout2>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
namespace InflationWithStyle
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        }
    }

    public class RelativeLayout2 : RelativeLayout
    {
        public RelativeLayout2(Context context, IAttributeSet attributeSet) 
            : base(context, attributeSet, 0, Resource.Style.RelativeLayout2)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update** (2018.09.12)

I tried styling a `TextView` as well, and set it's style's parent to *`android:Widget.TextView`* but it also had no effect.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="TextView2" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
  <item name="android:background">#204090</item>
</style>
```

**TextView2**

```
public class TextView2 : TextView
{
    public TextView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attributeSet) 
        : base(context, attributeSet, 0, Resource.Style.TextView2)
    {
    }
}
```

**activity_main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InflationWithStyle.RelativeLayout2 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appNS="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/InflationWithStyle.InflationWithStyle"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
  <!--style="@style/RelativeLayout2"-->
  <!--appNS:style1="@style/RelativeLayout2"-->

    <InflationWithStyle.TextView2
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="asdfasdfasdfasfasfasdfasfdasdfasfasdf"
      />
  <!--style="@style/TextView2"-->

</InflationWithStyle.RelativeLayout2>
```

Answer (score -1):

> The following constructor call attempts to style my custom RelativeLayout2 using the defStyleRes parameter but it has no effect.

Neither the [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) documentation nor the [Style resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource) documentation implies that the `//style/@name` value can be a `View` name and have things "magically linked". Instead, they both use a `style` attribute on the View, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomeView.RelativeLayout2 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/RelativeLayout2">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="An utter lack of style."/>

</CustomeView.RelativeLayout2>
```

I have tested your code with this method, it works fine.

Comment: The line in question is `base(context, attributeSet, 0, Resource.Style.RelativeLayout2)`. What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211576/passing-style-references-to-a-merge-layout